# Including a different image in SweetAlert2 popup message based on selection of a div after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sweetalert2

I think something similar to this question was answered in the past. However, I read a number of StackOverflow posts and still couldn't solve the issue. Probably, that is because I don't have a good understanding of jQuery yet and can't apply basic concepts to what I need to solve. So, I would greatly appreciate if you could help me solve this issue. Thanks!

Right now, what happens is the following:

1. When clicking a button in the middle, five circles show up.

2. When you click a circle, a popup message made with SweetAlert2 shows up.

3. When clicking the "ok" button in the popup message, the message is closed and you can see that the circle's background was changed to light orange.

**What I want to do** : show a different image(https://s25.postimg.cc/kw0l49gz3/original.png) in the popup message when clicking a circle with the text "okay". 

*Note*: I assigned "options" class for all circles and different id for each circle. The id for a circle with the text "okay" is "option5".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').click(function(){
  $(".options:hidden").fadeIn()
    .on("click", function(){
      $(this).css("background", "#F3C78D");
    })
    .on("click", function(){
      swal({
        title: 'Sweet!',
        text: 'Modal with a custom image.',
        imageUrl: 'https://unsplash.it/400/200',
        imageWidth: 400,
        imageHeight: 200,
        imageAlt: 'Custom image',
        animation: false
      })
      //  swal({
      //   title: 'Sweet!',
      //   text: 'Modal with a custom image.',
      //   imageUrl: 'https://s25.postimg.cc/kw0l49gz3/original.png',
      //   imageWidth: 400,
      //   imageHeight: 200,
      //   imageAlt: 'Custom image',
      //   animation: false
      // })
     });
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Poor Story', sans-serif;
}

#test{
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   display: flex;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.options {
    background: #f7f7f5;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #F3C78D;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.options span {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#option1{
    transform: translate(-100%, -150%);
}

#option2{
    transform: translate(-160%, -40%);
}

#option3{
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

#option4{
    transform: translate(60%, -40%);
}

#option5{
    transform: translate(15%, -150%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <!-- [Google Fonts] To embed your selected fonts into a webpage, copy this code into the <head> of your HTML document. -->
    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sunflower:300" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poor+Story" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.0 : jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <!-- sweetalert2 -->
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="test">test</button>
    <div class="options" id="option1"><span>Hello<br>World</span></div>
    <div class="options" id="option2"><span>Goodbye</span></div>
    <div class="options" id="option3"><span>How<br>are<br>you?</span></div>
    <div class="options" id="option4"><span>Fine</span></div>
    <div class="options" id="option5"><span>Okay</span></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use data-attribute to define the image link inside the element and then you can easily use it within the JS code. You can also do the same with the other parameter.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').click(function(){
  $(".options:hidden").fadeIn()
    .on("click", function(){
      $(this).css("background", "#F3C78D");
    })
    .on("click", function(){
      var url=$(this).attr('data-img');
      swal({
        title: 'Sweet!',
        text: 'Modal with a custom image.',
        imageUrl: url,
        imageWidth: 400,
        imageHeight: 200,
        imageAlt: 'Custom image',
        animation: false
      })

     });
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Poor Story', sans-serif;
}

#test{
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   display: flex;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.options {
    background: #f7f7f5;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%; 
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #F3C78D;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.options span {
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%; 
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#option1{
    transform: translate(-100%, -150%);
}

#option2{
    transform: translate(-160%, -40%);
}

#option3{
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

#option4{
    transform: translate(60%, -40%);
}

#option5{
    transform: translate(15%, -150%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.1.x -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <!-- [Google Fonts] To embed your selected fonts into a webpage, copy this code into the <head> of your HTML document. -->
    <!-- <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sunflower:300" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poor+Story" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap 4.0 : jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <!-- sweetalert2 -->
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.12.15/dist/sweetalert2.min.css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" id="test">test</button>
    <div class="options" data-img="https://unsplash.it/400/200" id="option1"><span>Hello<br>World</span></div>
    <div class="options" data-img="https://unsplash.it/400/200" id="option2"><span>Goodbye</span></div>
    <div class="options" data-img="https://unsplash.it/400/200" id="option3"><span>How<br>are<br>you?</span></div>
    <div class="options" data-img="https://unsplash.it/400/200" id="option4"><span>Fine</span></div>
    <div class="options" data-img="https://s25.postimg.cc/kw0l49gz3/original.png" id="option5"><span>Okay</span></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh, I see! Thanks! By the way, what should I do if I'd like to show a different popup message? https://jsfiddle.net/hlim188/15no3zyd/1/ (show a different popup message only for a circle with the text "okay")

Comment: Dear Termani, I wanted to apply what you taught me and I got stuck again... This time, I wanted to show a popup msg that required a user input by using "click: async function()". And, I didn't know how to apply what you taught me... https://jsfiddle.net/hlim188/15no3zyd/20/

Comment: @JL well, am not very used to this alert, you may probably add another question and you will get more help ;)